# How to list data from Firebase database in listview?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently creating an app which logs a 6-digit int id's (values) and the time/date they were logged (keys) in a real-time database. I am trying to create a separate app to accompany this by listing the database key-value as items on a list, with a search query to search the id's.

My question is, how I should go about retrieving and listing both the keys and values as items in my listView? The items need to add themselves in real-time as well, so they can be viewed as they would in the Firebase console. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do share relevant code snippets.

Comment: sry, I'll keep it in mind for later questions. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<String> arr;
public ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    arr = new ArrayList<>();

    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            map2list((Map) dataSnapshot.getValue());
            //formats the datasnapshot entries to strings
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //makes the ListView realtime
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            System.out.println(databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    };
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourOwnListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void map2list(Map<String,Long> map){

    arr.clear();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        Long key = Long.parseLong(entry.getKey());
        String d = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(key);
        Long value = entry.getValue();
        arr.add(d + ": " + value);
    }

}
```

I tested this on my own database and it works.

map2list() is my quick way of formatting your data for the listview. The best way to do this is with a custom arrayadapter or baseadapter, but that involves alot more code than you need for this example.

Be advised that keeping your keys as time is a bad idea since you could have a collision if two logs are made at the same time.

Lastly, firebase uses Longs over ints, so i used Longs for less code

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This code worked perfectly on my project. BTW, my scanner uploads once every other second, so I guess the collision was never going to be an issue in the first place, but thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Comment: What if I want to add an onItemClickListener on the listview item and open up a new activity which is displaying different data from firebase database. Is it possible?

Comment: Certainly possible, but separate from this question. To do that, attach the appropriate onItemClickListener to your listview. Then in the onItemClick abstract method, create a new intent that contains an extra related to the list item and point the intent to the new activity. After calling startActivity, do your necessary firebase retrieval in the new activity. Thats the high-level gist, if you want specifics open up a new SO question and point me to I and I'll be happy to answer.